# How to search and insert a value using java code?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
  String link = "http://hosted.ap.org";
```

I want to find whether the given url is already existing in the SQL DB under the table name "urls". If the given url is not found in that table i need to insert it in to that table.

As I am a beginner in Java, I cannot really reach the exact code.

Please advise on this regard on how to search the url in the table.

I am done with the SQL Connection using the java code. Please advise me on the searching and inserting part alone as explained above.

Comment: For what database?  And the table - it's called `URLS`, but what are the columns in it?  What have you tried so far, because we aren't here to provide you end-to-end solutions.

Comment: LNADWEEK is the database name.
I am done with the SQL Connection part.
There is only one column in it named URL, which has a list of 20000 URLs.

Comment: @BalusC could u please pitch in for this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between two completely separate things: [SQL (Structured Query Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is the language which you use to communicate with the DB. [JDBC (Java DataBase Connectivity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) is a Java API which enables you to execute SQL language using Java code.

To get data from DB, you usually use the [SQL `SELECT` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp). To insert data in a DB, you usually use the [SQL `INSERT INTO` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

To prepare a SQL statement in Java, you usually use [`Connection#prepareStatement()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29). To execute a SQL `SELECT` statement in Java, you should use [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29). It returns a [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) with the query results. To execute a SQL `INSERT` statement in Java, you should use [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29).

#### See also:

- [SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/)
- [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
PreparedStatement insert = connectin.preparedStateme("insert into urls(url) vlaues(?)");
PreparedStatement search = connectin.preparedStateme("select * from urls where url = ?");
search.setString(1, <your url value to search>);
ResultSet rs = search.executeQuery();
if (!rs.hasNext()) {
    insert.setString(1, <your url value to insert>);
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

//finally close your statements and connection
...

i assumed that you only have one field your table and field name is url. if you have more fields you need to add them in insert query.